# Como "destrinchar" um texto qualquer no momento do "echo" e transformar cada palavra em um link

Tags: php, jquery

Fiz um banco de dados e nesse banco de dados cadastro uma frase qualquer, gostaria que quando eu fosse dar o "echo" nessa frase, cada palavra se tornasse um link único. Ex:

```
recue o código em 4 espaços
```

A frase é simples, porém gostaria que cada palavra criasse um link. O objetivo disso é melhorar os meios de buscas.

Na frase de exemplo tem a palavra **código**. Caso eu clique na palavra **código** eu gostaria de ir pra uma pagina de pesquisa que usasse essa palavra.

Usar a palavra é simples, o problema maior é destrinchar essa frase e transformar cada palavra em um link.

Comment: Algumas horas esmagando os botões do meu mouse pra fazer uma arma atirar adequadamente num ET acabou em UTI. Re-adicionado. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso é um sistema de tags, geralmente são palavras chave e não parte de um texto. Deveriam ser individuais e não uma frase.

```
$str = 'recue o código em 4 espaços';
$str = explode( ' ' , $str );

foreach( $str as $palavra )
{
    if( mb_strlen( $palavra ) > 3 )
    echo '<a href="'.$palavra.'">'.$palavra.'</a>';
}
```

Perceba que cada palavra será um link. Adicionei uma verificação para aceitar palavras maiores que 3 caracteres.

Exemplo no [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/s41urs)

Comment: Boa `+1`. Eu pensei que era em JS. Vamos ver quem acertou... Depois de reler a pergunta acho que a tua resposta é a certa :P

Comment: todas as respostas foram ótimas e funcionais, porém a tua se destaco por ser mais simples e ter uma aplicação mais facil

Comment: Isso é preconceito contra códigos assustadoramente cabeludos e complexos. :D

Comment: kkkkk @BrunoAugusto na próxima eu fico com o código mais complexo, pode ser? kkkk

Comment: Você é quem sabe. Mas se fica a dica, estude o meu código. COm ele você aprende um pouco sobre loops não interpretáveis (mais rápidos que um foreach, por exemplo), [Closures](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.anonymous.php) e assustadoramente fantástica [sprintf()](http://www.php.net/sprintf). E aprendendo sobre sprintf() automaticamente você já está apto a utilizar suas primas printf(), sscanf(), fscanf() e vsprintf(). Péra... Usar as primas ficou meio pornográfco pra esse site... :D

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, cada um com suas ferramentas :) Mas o bacana é essa possibilidade de fazer a mesma coisa de formas diferentes. Não me assustaria se sua resposta fosse a mais votada.

Answer (score 4):

#### Em JavaScript:

Para partir essa frase nos espaços em branco pode fazer desta maneira:

```js
var frase = 'recue o código em 4 espaços';
var palavras = frase.split(' ');
var links = palavras.map(function(palavra) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    var casulo = document.createElement('div');
    link.href = '?busca=' + palavra;
    link.innerHTML = palavra;
    casulo.appendChild(link);
    return casulo.innerHTML;
});
document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = links.join(' ');
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Isto é uma maneira simplificada, podia juntar mais verificações como por exemplo eliminar palavras curtas como `ou`, `a`, `é` etc...

A variável `links` vai ter uma array de ancoras com o texto da palavra.

Comment: pode ser em ambos os lados. Com JS é comum ver o destaque de palavras em links patrocinados e a facilidade de incorporar outras funcionalidades.

Comment: Como o foco do rapaz é *SEO*, os mecanismos de busca vão reconhecer os links criados pelo JS? [Minha dúvida]

Comment: @PapaCharlie hoje em dia sei que o Google já analiza JS, mas a maneira correta para isso é mesmo do lado do servidor.

Comment: Só não entendi a necessidade do `cloneNode` já que está encapsulado...

Comment: @KaduAmaral nem eu :P Devia ser parte de alguma ideia que tive e abandonei, esquecendo de corrigir o código. Retirei.

Comment: Eu acho que tu ia criar o nó uma vez e reutiliza-lo em um loop ou algo assim. :P rsrs, bacada +1

Answer (score 2):

E que comecem os jogos! :D

Outra abordagem:

```
$str = 'recue o código em 4 espaços';

echo implode( ' ',

    array_map(

        function( $word ) {
            return sprintf( '<a href="%1$s">%1$s</a>', $word );
        },

        explode( ' ', $str )
    )
);
```

Se não quiser que as palavras continuem unidas por um espaço do jeito que eram antes da substituição, basta remover o implode().